# How to upload image from Ext.img to server in Sencha Touch and PhoneGap using JSON

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am working in Sencha Touch. I have to upload an image using it.
I get the image from PhoneGap and set it to Ext.img src.
Now I want to upload that image to a  server using JSON.
Can any one give some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use phonegap's FileTransfer. There's a nice example on the api docs.

Take a look at:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Hope it helps-